# Regex expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make an name validation Regex expression, to check, if name is passed in correct format. It needs to be in format like - 'John', 'Sarah', so, no whitespaces allowed, no other characters allowed and no numbers allowed. Also, the first letter has to be capital, and all other letters following has to be non capital letters.

I have tried writing some regex expressions and checking them on regexr, but expression that works there, does not work correctly in C#

Can someone share solution to exclude any other character, that IS NOT a letter?

For me it seems, that there are some differences between regex used on regexr and regex used in C# and thats why the expression that works on regexr, does not work in C#

Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT:
For example:
Expression is - `([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)\w+`.
In regexr, it has to be 1st capital letter, then any other letter, all whitespaces or other characters excluded. When I copy this in my C# project, it still allows to write whitespaces or other symbols like . ; , etc.

EDIT2:
C# implementation looks like this:

```
            string name = nameCapitalLetterCheck_textBox.Text.ToString();
            string nameFormat = @"([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)\w+";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(name,nameFormat))
            {
                nameCapitalLetterCheck_result.Text = "OK";
                nameCapitalLetterCheck_result.Foreground = green;
                nameCapital_hint.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                nameCapitalLetterCheck_result.Text = "Error";
                nameCapitalLetterCheck_result.Foreground = red;
                nameCapital_hint.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
```

Comment: As your question stands, you are just requesting that a regex be written for you. Instead, you should show your effort so far and give us details about the problem being encountered.

Comment: Can you share what your C# implementation looks like?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to give an example of what I've tried

Comment: C# implementation added @Collen

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch` will return true if it finds a match to your regex anywhere in the string. It doesn't necessarily mean that it matched the whole string. You should look at using `^` and `$` operators in your regex.

Comment: So I need to add ```^``` for something that is at the start of the string and ```$``` for something that is at the end of the string? I did not quite understand this, because I am begginer in usin regex

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has pointed it out, but your requirements for what counts for a name is very restrictive. My friend Patrick O'Connor would take offence. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Where I live, we have names, that are matching this format, so i dont quite need any other format of name. I did not say, that only this format of name counts as a name ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\z
```

See [proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cp%7bLu%7d%5cp%7bLl%7d%2b%5cz&i=Sarah)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{Lu}                    any uppercase character
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{Ll}+                  any lowercase character (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!